# Connect to RDS instance via MYSQL workbench without a static IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I have an RDS instance that only accepts incoming requests from my EC2 instance. I want to connect MySQLWorkbench to the RDS instance, however, I use a VPN, and don't want to allow a specific IP address access to the RDS, as my local IP address changes frequently. Can I connect to my RDS instance using a PEM key or similar approach?

Comment: Does your RDS instance have a public IP?

Comment: Add your vpn ip address to the security group for the RDS. dont need to worry about local IP if you are connecting over VPN.

Comment: Is the VPN Hosted on AWS and does it route traffic between the home network and the AWS VPC? Or is this something more of a privacy thing? Like PIA or Nord VPN?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MySQL Workbench allows you to connect to databases using **Standard TCP/IP over SSH**

Since you've got an EC2 instance running, simply use the EC2's public IP, username and you can use the PEM as an authentication method.

```
ssh -o "ExitOnForwardFailure yes" -p 22 -fN ec2-user@123.456.789.XXX -L localhost:3360:rds-conn-url:3306
```

This is a **non-login shell** (`N`) so your terminal will hang when connected.

[image]

Alternatively, if you're using a Unix based system, you can make SSH tunnel to the EC2 instance and then use the port binding with **Standard TCP/IP** connection

Comment: you are making an assumption that the RDS instance has a public IP address.

Comment: @ptierno No, I'm making an assumption that EC2 instance has a public IP. The description already states that EC2 can access the RDS, I'm simply proxying the connection over the EC2.

Comment: vpn though.. much simpler solution.

Comment: That's overcomplication to if you just need to access the MySQL database. If there are other use cases than just that. Yes, VPN is a better solution.

Comment: the OP is using a VPN already. and a VPN is a pretty standard solution to managing cloud resources. Nothing about it is overly complicated.

Comment: From the sentence what I understood is that VPN is something like a privacy-related thing. Like PIA or Nord VPN. Not a self-hosted one that route traffic to between home network and AWS VPC. Maybe, I should've asked for clarification. Thanks for the feedback @ptierno

Comment: same, i should have asked for clarification